# Creating a bitmap file in C++

Tags: c++, windows, bitmap

I am trying to create a bitmap file in C++ with no libraries. I've tried this code and it doesn't work. I also want to be able to edit the pixels in a bitmap image. According to my code this should create a bitmap file with no image data, but shouldn't the bitmap image open up at least? It says it is corrupted.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include <Windows.h>

int main() {

  FILE *fileBuffer = NULL;
  fileBuffer = fopen("test.bmp", "w");

  BITMAPFILEHEADER *fileHeader = new BITMAPFILEHEADER;
  BITMAPINFOHEADER *infoHeader = new BITMAPINFOHEADER;

  int imageWidth = 0;
  int imageHeight = 0;

  fileHeader->bfType = 'BM';
  fileHeader->bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER);
  fileHeader->bfReserved1 = 0;
  fileHeader->bfReserved2 = 0;
  fileHeader->bfOffBits = 54;

  fwrite(fileHeader, 1, 14, fileBuffer);

  infoHeader->biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
  infoHeader->biWidth = imageWidth;
  infoHeader->biHeight = imageHeight;
  infoHeader->biPlanes = 1;
  infoHeader->biBitCount = 24;
  infoHeader->biCompression = BI_RGB;
  infoHeader->biSizeImage = sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) * imageWidth * imageHeight;
  infoHeader->biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
  infoHeader->biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
  infoHeader->biClrImportant = 0;
  infoHeader->biClrUsed = 0;

  fwrite(infoHeader, 1, 40, fileBuffer);
  fclose(fileBuffer);

  delete fileHeader;
  delete infoHeader;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the software you use to check does not like 0x0 px images. I cannot tell if any other would – mind you, I've never tried either.

Comment: bfType='MB' is the correct way. The bytes get swapped when you write them to a file.

Comment: The computation of biSizeImage is also incorrect. For BI_RGB, each image line must be a multiple of 4 bytes. However, as @fassl said, the reason you are getting a "corrupted" error is because the magic bytes are reversed.